# How can i create a new html page with the name of title, by using forms in HTML

Tags: html

how to create a new html page by using forms in HTML or javascript. I want to use the title for the page name and url..

Comment: could you show us your code? It's unclear what you mean at the moment - you change the title of a web page with `<title></title>` tags in the `<head>`

Comment: Where are you planning to create this HTML page? On your server? You'll need some form of server-side programming for that. Not possible using only HTML or client-side programming.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, this is what you need to do for i title.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML Reference</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```